# Copy click events, destroy them and attach them later

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to completely disable the click events for some elements but to have the option to reenable them later.

What I have try so far:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
   // some stuffs...
});

...

$('a').each(function(i, el) {
   this.clickEvents = $._data(el, 'events').click;
   $(el).off('click');
});

// reenable them later (this is not working)
$('a').each(function(i, el) {
   $(el).on('click', this.clickEvents);
});

...
```

Any ideas where I'm wrong?

Comment: Try assigning it into an array, **[For ex](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-do-i-copy-the-click-event-from-one-element-to-another)** or store it in any `data-*` attribute of each element

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Sorry, i didn't understand, could you be more specific?

Comment: @nevermind I don't understand your question, do you only want to stop all click handlers and be able to reactivate later, or do you want to store all click events and dispatch them later? for the former, the easiest solution is using CSS [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: @kaiido pointer-events doesn't work for old IEs, I want to store all click events of an element, totally delete them, and after a bit time later to have the option to reassign them later...sorry for the bad english

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `.handler` in each `clickEvent`:

```
$('a').each(function(i, el) {
   // clickEventHandlers is an array of handler functions
   this.clickEventHandlers = $._data(el, 'events').click.map(function(e) {
      return e.handler;
   });
   $(el).off('click');
});

// re-enable them later
$('a').each(function(i, el) {
   // reapply the handlers in order
   this.clickEventHandlers.forEach(function(handler) {
      $(el).on('click', handler);
   });
});
```

The great thing about this is that you re-apply **all** event listeners **in order**.

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usandfriends/c5sze7q6/).

Comment: hm, I've tested it and it still not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: @usandfriends - now I understand what is going on here... thanks for the example

Answer (score 1):

Try `$._data(el, 'events').click[0].handler` for first `click` event , or use `$.each()` to iterate all `click` or other events ; store `handler` at element `.data()` ; e.g., `.data("events")` ; reattach handler using `$(this).data().events[0]`

```js
$("a").data("events", []).on("click", function() {
  console.log(this)
});

$("a").each(function(i, el) {
  $.each($._data(el, 'events').click, function(index, event) {
    $(el).data().events.push(event.handler)
  })
  console.log($(this).data("events"));
  $(el).off("click");
});

// reenable them later (this is not working)
$("a").each(function(i, el) {
  $.each($(this).data().events, function(index, handler) {
    $(el).on("click", handler);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">click</a>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of what you changed and why.

Comment: that's fun the three answers kept the `(this is not working)` comment :-)